# encoder - decoder для объекта NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, ios

Прошу помочь новичку: нужно сохранить и восстановить (через архивирование и `UserDefaults`) экземпляр, в свойстве которого объект `NSTimer`. Понимаю, что `encode/decodeОbject: forKey:` не сработает. Еще раз прошу помощи в решении задачи. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть в исходники NSTimer, то видно, что NSTimer не следует протоколу NSCoding. Значит он не сериализуется для сохранения.
Можно попробывать создать категорию и в ней уже добавить поддержку этого протокола. А вообще таймеры используются для того, чтобы с периодичностью вызывать какую-то функцию, не вижу смысла сохранять его.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вообще его сохранять? Что вам это даст? В `initWithCoder:` просто создавайте новый таймер с нуля.